# MySQL not updating after calling connection.commit() with Flask (WORKING)

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I'm using flask to build a simple web app but for whatever reason the conn.commit() is not committing the data into the database. I know this because when I manually add something to the database the data doesn't change but the ID section increases each time I test it (because its using auto increment). So basically my current table has ID 1, Username test, Password test and the next entry that I inserted manually (after trying to use my application) was ID 5, Username blah, Password blah. Is there any specific reason that the commit isn't working?

EDIT: I had to change cursor = mysql.connect().cursor() to conn.cursor()

```
@app.route('/add_data/')
def add_tv_to_database():
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO _accounts VALUES (null, 'test','test')")
    conn.commit()
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Does the commit cause an exception?

Comment: no its running fine and has no exceptions it just for whatever reason doesn't want to post the data into the table

Comment: Ok, I just got it working and updated the post, all I had to do was change cursor = mysql.connect().cursor() to cursor = conn.connect() what was happening was I was establishing two different connections to the database so I was unable to update!

Comment: Hey @josh. I'm getting the AttributeError 'Connection' object has no attribute 'connect'. Did you get this too? I tried your changes. You know what's up?

Answer (score 2):

In the fourth line of your code, change it from `cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()` to `cursor = conn.cursor()`. This will ensure that the cursor uses the existing connection to database (from the previous line of code), instead of creating a new MySQL connection.