# Can't commit mysql query from Python

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask, commit

I'm trying to get a small Flask app working that writes to a MySQL database, but it seems like the database commit isn't working and I have no idea why.

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'eggsited'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()

cursor.execute('insert into user (id, first_name, last_name) values (%s, %s, %s)', ['324325', 'Kristoffer', 'Nielsen'])
conn.commit()
```

That's the part that deals with inserting values into my table. I know that my connection is working since I can do select statements and list the results from those and the execute statement is working too, because when I insert a new row directly in mysql the auto incremented id field has been incremented. So it must be the commit command that isn't actually committing the execute statement, but I have no idea why.

Is there something obvious that I have missed?

Comment: "isn't working" as in you're getting an error message or "isn't working" as in my data isn't in the DB?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Should have explained that better. It's not working as in my data isn't in the DB. I'm not getting any error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this question: [MySQL not updating after calling connection.commit() with Flask (WORKING)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26809563/4557439)

In the third last line of your code, change it from `cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()` to `cursor = conn.cursor()`. This will ensure that the cursor uses the existing connection to database (from the previous line of code), instead of creating a new MySQL connection.

Comment: This is exactly what's wrong! Thank you so much :-) It makes a lot of sense the way you explained it too!